# XSLT - Ampersand in &amp; entity breaking transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am doing my transformation in php.

I am receiving a large XML file to transform - which works fine however inside a node there is a url that contains the & character (encoded to `&amp;`) ie

```
<web:cacheurl>http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=adewy&amp;d=4573100964054074&amp;w=95e613ec,b3e54511</web:cacheurl>
```

All well and good I thought, however the & in the `&amp;` appears to be breaking any transformations on that node AND all nodes that appear after it in the xml.

If I strip all & out of the XML to just amp; the problem is fixed, hence debugged - I really don't want to have to strip them out and then put them back in after the transformation, it's a bit hacky.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please say exactly what you did and exactly what happened. "Appears to be breaking any transformations" isn't precise enough for a diagnosis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I cannot reproduce this alleged problem.**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (with added namespace declaration, to make it well-formed):

```
<web:cacheurl xmlns:web="some:web">http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=adewy&amp;d=4573100964054074&amp;w=95e613ec,b3e54511</web:cacheurl>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<web:cacheurl xmlns:web="some:web">http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=adewy&amp;d=4573100964054074&amp;w=95e613ec,b3e54511</web:cacheurl>
```

**this same result is produced by all nine XSLT (both 1.0 and 2.0) processors that I use**.

Comment: You are right, it is not the issue. Something somewhere else in the XML is causing this to become a problem somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using Saxon 9.1 xslt processor in Stylus studio 2011.
When using Microsoft MSXML 6 processor, problem disappeared.

**Update:**

problem only occurs when using ampersand in value of attribute...